# Renaming many folders in PowerShell

Tags: string, variables, powershell, rename

I have over 1000+ files that have to be renamed.

The first set folder and/or files are grouped by location, so the first four characters are the same for each file; there are four-five different locations.  I need to delete the first few characters of the folder's name.

Example:

> Old File: ABC_Doe, Jane
>   New File: Doe, Jane

any suggestions as to the quickest way to carry this out?

I've tried all of the following:

```
  1st Attempt 
  $a = Get-ChildItem C:\example
  $b = Where-Object {$_.name -like “*ABC_*”}
  $cmdlet_name = “Rename-Item”
  $d = (cmdlet_name $a $b)
  invoke-expression $d

  2nd Attempt 
  $e = Get-ChildItem C:\example
  $f = $e.TrimStart (“ABC_”)
```

3rd Attempt

```
Rename-Item -{$_.name -like “*ASD*”, “”}
```

Comment: You are just blindly shooting in the dark. Why don't you read up some basics of Powershell and then start with it?

Comment: @manojilds at least he's trying? many post here without any prior effort at all...

Comment: @x0n - and those get downvoted and closed etc...just saying since he is wasting time doing random things and some basic intro would save a lot of time. And wouldn't have bothered to comment on the questions where the OP had not tried anything.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, get all child items (files only), remove abc_ by replacing them (with nothing) and rename each file. To rename files in sub-directories add the -Recurse switch to the Get-ChildItem command:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\example -Filter ABC_* | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '^ABC_') + $_.Extension }
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, this should work as well and is much shorter (no need to append the file extension cause renaming is performed on the file name).

```
Get-ChildItem c:\example -Filter ABC_* | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^ABC_' }
```

Comment: Add `-verbose` to the `rename-item` to get a listing of what is changed. Or a `-WhatIf` to list what would be changed (but not change anything).

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childItem ABC_* | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace 'ABC_','' }
```

Source: [`get-help rename-item -full`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315353.aspx)